# Sequence divisible by a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Consider a general arithmetic sequence $x_j = y + jn, j \ge 1$. Prove that if $p$
>   is a prime number such that $p \nmid n$ then there is some element from the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that is divisible by $p$.
>
> Your proof of this result should give you a method which for a given arithmetic
>   sequence and prime actually allows you to calculate a point in the sequence at
>   which the divisibility property holds. Illustrate your method by presenting an
>   element from this sequence that is divisible by $p$, where
>   $p = 150000001 = 1.5 × 10^8 + 1$, and where $n=14506349$ and $y=2021$.

Does anyone have a clue on how to tackle this?

Comment: This problem sounds like it was lifted word-for-word off an exam or something.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? Can you try a couple of examples by hand?

Comment: $\!\bmod p\!:\ nj+y\equiv 0\iff nj\equiv -y\iff j\equiv -y\,n^{-1},\,$ and the inverse exists by Bezout and $\,p\nmid n.\, $  See the linked dupe for many ways to compute such inverses (and modular fractions).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of how to start:
There is an algorithm that produces integers x and z such that $$ xp + zn =gcd(p,n) $$
Since p is prime and p does not divide n, gcd(p,n)=1. $$ xp + zn =1 $$
$$ xyp + yzn=y $$
Let j=-yz. You can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use congruences: you have to show some $x_j\equiv 0\mod p$ – explicitly
$$ y+jn\equiv 0 \mod p.$$
Remember that, if a prime $p$ does not divide $n$, $n$ is invertible modulo $p$ (by Bézout's identity).